# How to display UItableView as in a Panel

Tags: iphone, xcode4, uitableview

I have a client who wants to offer options on the first page of their new app as they appear in his website. The options appear in a panel like below.

[image]

This is possible for an iPhone but I'm unsure how to go about it. Has someone done something like this before?

Comment: so you need to make tableview look like your above image?

Comment: Your table view cell has one property that you can set. That's cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton; 
But I promise you'll not get exact of above image for that you need to make custom cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create your own custom cell, and the asign it to the Table, is quite easy once you have done it a couple of times.

check for ex here:

http://blog.webscale.co.in/?p=284